# Simplest Express route is returning 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this minimal setup in my node application:

server.js

```
/**
* Starting point for the backend
*/
'use strict'

const app = require('./app');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  require('dotenv').config();
} else {
  console.log("Production mode is on");
}

const port = process.env.NODE_LOCAL_PORT;
const host = process.env.HOST;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on http://${host}:${port} `);
});
```

app.js

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config();
require('express-async-errors');

/* Spaceholder for routes */
const availabilityRoutes = require('./routes/availability');
const inventoryRoutes = require('./routes/inventory');
const overviewRoutes = require('./routes/overview');
const utilisationRoutes = require('./routes/utilisation');

const app= express();
app.use(express.json());

// For testing purpose
const routes = express.Router();
routes.get('/test', async(req, res, next) => {
  console.log("test");
  res.send("test");
});

/* Register the modules containing the routes */
app.use(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/api/availability', availabilityRoutes);
app.use(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/api/inventory', inventoryRoutes);
app.use(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/api/overview', overviewRoutes);
app.use(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/api/utilisation', utilisationRoutes);

app.use((req,res,next) => {
  res.sendStatus(404);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Example controller for /api/availability

```
const express = require('express');
const routes = express.Router();
const cors = require('cors');

const helper = require('../helper');

const allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:4000'];

//delete for prod or test env
const whitelist = {
  origin: function(origin, callback) {
    if(origin && allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) == -1){
      let errorMsg = 'The CORS policy for this site does not allow access from the specified Origin.';
      return callback(new Error(errorMsg), false);
    }
    //for calls from the same host the browser do not put the origin
    return callback(null, true);
  }
}

//global for the entire module
const queries = helper.readJSONfile();

routes.get('/', cors(whitelist), async(req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Hello");
    res.send("Hello");
    helper.getApiCall(req, res, queries.availability.overview);
});
```

dependencies:

```
"@influxdata/influxdb-client": "^1.14.0",
"@influxdata/influxdb-client-apis": "^1.14.0",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"dotenv": "^10.0.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
"mysql": "^2.18.1",
"nodemon": "^2.0.9"
```

Even if I want to call `http://localhost:4000/test` I get a 404 "Not Found" returned and I have no clue why.

Comment: The Router you create, routes, doesn't seem to get used anywhere.

Comment: @jonrsharpe There is `routes.get('/test', async(req, res, next) => {` for testing, so this should be at least called.

Comment: Yes, you've registered a route on the router, but you haven't actually linked that router to the app anywhere...

Comment: @jonrsharpe In this case, how would I link it, so I can try to resolve this error?

Comment: For testing, you may use like `app.use(routes);`

Comment: Look at how you're linking all of the _other_ routers you import into `app.js`, or read e.g. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router.

Comment: But main problem is below **Register the modules containing the routes**,  you need to remove  `process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `

Comment: @ArifKhan But how could I prepend a string from my `.env` something to the routes?

Comment: In `/api/availability` You need to add `module.export = routes;`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `app.get()`   instead of `routes.get()`

Comment: Why should one do that? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, you have used a middleware which sends status code 404 since the intended code for routing doesn't work. This middleware precisely:

```
app.use((req,res,next) => {
  res.sendStatus(404);
});
```

And the code won't work until you use the router correctly. Use routes.route('/test').get( .... ) it will start working.

I maybe wrong, I'm also learning as of now, if I'm wrong, do tell me.